# Dry orgasm on Ramadan

Tags: sawm, sex, ramadan, masturbation, iftar

So I have decided to fast for Ramadan for the first time this year and have kept the dry fast decently so far.  But, I have a masturbation addiction.  I know it’s considered as haram whether it’s Ramadan or not, but the least I want to do is to at least not break the fast during this month.

I did search and found out that if you don’t ejaculate semen, then the fast is still valid.  However, I did not find any source that specified about orgasm.  I did orgasm, but did not ejaculate.

But is the fast still valid?  And if it’s broken now, do I eat normally or do I still wait for iftar?  Also, do I really have to do the 60 people feeding etc?  Not able to afford that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that sawm of Ramadan or fast in Ramadan or generally in Islam means abstaining, usually from food, drink, and sexual activity during the day one intends to fast.

So you can have sexual activity between maghreb and fajr. And of course you can eat and drink during this time.

Secondly according to the majority view masturbation is regarded as haram (I've shared the major evidence for that in: [Is hands free masturbation worse or the same as with hands?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65370/is-hands-free-masturbation-worse-or-the-same-as-with-hands/)). However  it is also regarded as rather makruh by prominent scholars like ibn Hazm (who quoted some mostly weak evidences on the topic), ibn Taymiyyah and imam Ahmad and therefore it can be permitted under certain conditions because masturbation at least is better than committing adultery. Therefore some hanafi and hanbali scholars permitted it in case of fear of committing zina.

Thirdly if you didn't ejaculate while masturbating directly or soon afterwards you are not required to perform ghusl and therefore your fast wouldn't be broken.

As you are aware that you are not able to afford the kaffarah for invalidating your fast intentionally, you should avoid such bad habits. And you must repent for what you've done especially if you've done this by day time!

The following is an advice and as such it is not the standard for stackexchange since we avoid giving advice! Start by today to avoid masturbating during the day time totally, if possible since the last 10 days of Ramadan started avoid it also on the nights or reduce the frequency to the maximum possible. And for the future try step by step  to increase the time intervals between the individual acts of masturbation till you get married then you should be able to avoid it totally. Of course it might be necessary to find the reasons and triggers for your addiction and try to eliminate them one by one.

Else see also:
[What does someone have to do if he/she masturbate while in fast state during Ramadan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11129/what-does-someone-have-to-do-if-he-she-masturbate-while-in-fast-state-during-ram)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to confirm my inquiry and also adding wisdom and intuitive insight.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that Ramadan continues I am becoming more self-conscious of it and that it feels more wrong during this time.  Interestingly, the body seems to retain more easily automatically.  I think this is by grace and will of the Almighty.

Comment: Completing with the reasons for the masturbation is a good idea.  I already know a main one so will have to work on that one definitely.  Thanks again

Comment: Your answer is focusing more on the permissibility of this, instead, try to just put the answers as per the scholars and facts and let the viewers decide what they take from that as musterbation is considered a major sin and haram to various scholars.

Comment: @smali first of all the focus of this question is to answer whether the fast is invalidated or not this is covered here. Whether masturbation is haram or makruh isn't the main topic so please focus on the part that answers the question. It is meaningless to discuss a topic on layman level on which scholars have different positions. And my opinion is that masturbation is better than adultery and insisting that it is haram is a hardship for some people and it would be a reason for them to hate reject Islam or become hypocrites, which certainly isn't the goal of our shari'a.